# Project is not compatible with Xamarin iOS 10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[![Xamarin][1]][1][image]

While developing my application, I encountered an error related to the NuGet. Can someone help me with the error and do I know the best way to fix it?
Error: Project is not compatible with Xamarin iOS 10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64).

Comment: what is "an error related to nuget"?  Which nuget package is causing the problem?  Why does your iOS project have a reference to your Android project?  That seems a more likely cause of the problem than nuget.

Comment: You are referencing FoodDev.Android in your iOS native project